# Most elegant way to stop a function executing on the first call?

Tags: javascript, loops, iterator

I'm dealing with a stubborn API, and I need to stop a function executing on the *first* call, and then execute normally afterwards.

Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
var counter = 0;

function notFirstTime() {
    counter++;
    if (counter > 2) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: what is the purpose of stopping the execution?

Comment: removed one line of code :)  


var counter = 0;

function notFirstTime() {
    if (++counter > 2)  {return;
    }
}

Comment: @gurvinder372 That doesn't matter in context of the question

Comment: it matters since what you are doing is already functional and it sounds like an XY problem to me.http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @gurvinder372 No, don't think so. An API I am using calls this function on pageload, but I don't want it to run on pageload, but rather user action.

Comment: the question is unclear. "to stop a function executing on the first call" - you want to break the first function call on some line or you want to pass only first call and prevent further function calls?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest "I need to stop a function executing on the first call, and then execute normally afterwards." Pretty clear.

Comment: `var foo = function() { if(called) return; called = true; /*exec further*/}), called;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use function that "returns function" for such cases:

```
function skipFirstCall(fun) {
  var first_called = true;
  return function() {
    if (!first_called) {       
       fun.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    first_called = false;
  }
}

var myFunc = skipFirstCall(function(){
   console.log("I was executed!");
});

myFunc();
myFunc(); // I was executed!
myFunc(); // I was executed!
myFunc(); // I was executed!
```

You can pass any function to `skipFirstCall` function as argument to skip its first call:

```
var myAnotherFunc = skipFirstCall(function(){
   console.log("myAnotherFunc was executed!");
});

myAnotherFunc();
myAnotherFunc(); // myAnotherFunc was executed!
myAnotherFunc(); // myAnotherFunc was executed!
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes! there's a simple and elegant solution - you can redefine the function on the first call, like so:

```
var foo = function() {
  foo = function() {
    console.log("i'm after the 1st call");
  }
}
```

The first time you call `foo()`, it rewrites the `foo` variable and sets it to a new function.

Comment: Performance? `var foo = function() { if(called) return; called = true; /*exec further*/}), called;`